# How would an artist be able to sell their own music for Bitcoin?

Tags: merchants, ecommerce, merchant-services

What options are there for artists to market their Music in exchange for Bitcoin? How would an artist be able to directly sell his work to his fans?

Comment: This is a fantastic question. I've got a client who is a well known artist and I've yet to push the Bitcoin integration because Coinbase essentially handles the whole situation. I'd love to know if being the *middle man* in setting up BTC payments was worthwhile or if Coinbase/Bitpay is the only real option.

Comment: It rather depends on if you are a signed artist or not. Signed artists have to go through the various processes of collecting and distribution, unsigned artists are free to set up a simple Bitpay account for example, and generate direct sales online. If not you could print a QR on your merchandise or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding this question, its probably worthwhile to check out Bittunes. The company was started in May 2013 with the mission to enable the monetization of file sharing with Bitcoin. The significance of this is that it is not about just using Bitcoin as a way to buy music, but actually incentivising buys (fans) to serve as a new kind of distribution channel for music. ~ In other words, its an 'earning platform' for both artists and fans. It is early days for the system, with many aspects still to roll out. see:  www.bittunes.com and www.bittunes.org for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

[Liberty Music Store is a place to buy and sell music with Bitcoin](http://libertymusicstore.net/). It is geared towards simple user experience. The artist can keep 100%.

(disclaimer: I am the author)

Answer (score 1):

If I was an artist, I would have bitpay integrated to my Website, or direct people to an online store like Cryptothrift where my song would be listed and they can purchase it there with bitcoins.